# How to show/hide div in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to show `<div nameClass="showName">` when button is clicked and `this.state.name`'s value is not null.
The showResult state check name's value is null or not, but this isn't work I guess.
I don't know how to fix it.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class PhoneForm extends Component{
state = {
    name : '',
    showResults : false
}
handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        name: e.target.value
    })
}
onClick=(e)=>{
    this.setState({
        showResults: this.state.name===null ? false : true
    })
}
render(){
    return (
        <form>
            <input
                placeholder="name"
                value={this.state.name}
                onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <button onClick={this.onCkick}>클릭!</button>
                <div nameClass="showName" style={{display:(this.state.showResults? 'block':'none')}}>{this.state.name}</div>
        </form>
    );
}}


export default PhoneForm;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a small typo in your render method. Your change event handler is called `onClick`, not `onCkick`.

You must also make sure to use `preventDefault` on the event when the form is submitted, or the browser will reload.

```js
class PhoneForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    showResults: false
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value
    });
  };

  onClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      showResults: this.state.name === null ? false : true
    });
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          placeholder="name"
          value={this.state.name}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>클릭!</button>
        <div
          nameClass="showName"
          style={{ display: this.state.showResults ? "block" : "none" }}
        >
          {this.state.name}
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<PhoneForm />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the input is empty it will show nothing hence we don't need to check whether the input has a value or not.

What is needed to to toggle the visibility for on the `onClick` function.

Set the  `<button/>` type attribute to 'button' if you dont want to refresh the page all the time.

like: `<button type="button" onClick={this.onClick}>클릭!</button>`

Or trigger the `preventDefault()` on the event.

```js
class PhoneForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    showResults: true
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value,
      showResults: true
    });
  };

  onClick = e => {
    
    this.setState({
      showResults: !this.state.showResults 
    });
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          placeholder="name"
          value={this.state.name}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <button type="button" onClick={this.onClick}>클릭!</button>
        <div
          nameClass="showName"
          style={{ display: this.state.showResults ? "block" : "none" }}
        >
          {this.state.name}
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<PhoneForm />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It helps. Now my project works good. really thanks again. :)

Comment: Its a pleasure. If my answer was any help to you, I would appreciate an upvote